# LoopBack 4 - why it was published if its not a finished product

Tags: orm, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have experience with Sequelize and TypeORM. LoopBack looks like a good alternative, so I tested it. But it looks like LoopBack 4 is not a finished product; it barely has the needed features for a production application.

My question is: why the LoopBack team decided to publish an unfinished product?

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of companies and products on live using Loopback4.
Which features you missed from the new version?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. Which companies are using Looback4 in production? How can be used without, for example, many-to-many relations, or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, the product is free, open source and built off of previously released, finished products. Releasing it allows them to both test functionality and be provided with feedback and aid in building the actual application. Lots of products are released before they are finished for these important reasons. If you read the documentation, it is a community built product.
Most frameworks are constantly being updated to add functionality, so 'finished' is not really a word that can be thrown around for a framework
While it is not finished, to say it barely has the needs to support a production application is very dependent on the type of application being built.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean: as an alfa release for testing is good, but they are promoting it as Loobpack 4, when they should promote it as Loopback 4 Alpha or Beta or whatever to explicitly state that is not ready, and is in development/testing state. I can't imagine an application where I wont find the need of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Of course we can come up with some kind of basic app that wont use it, but it would be a waste of resources.